# Middle View Is Squeezed On 3.5 Inch Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, constraints

I"m encountering a constraint issue where the middle UIView in between two UIViews, one at the top and one at the bottom, is getting squeezed on a 3.5 inch iPhone screen (iPhone 4S). I'm not sure what's wrong with my constraints but here is what it looks like on iPhone 4S...

[image]

Here's what it's supposed to look like (iPhone 6)...

[image]

And finally here are the constraints...

[image]

Tell me if anymore information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Which view is "Camera View"? "Bottom View"? "Temp Image View"? "View"? "Camera Roll Button"?

Comment: @robmayoff Camera View is behind the middle one, temp image view is the middle one, bottom view is the gray bottom view, view is the top gray view, and camera roll button doesn't exist anymore and so does focus point (camera roll button and focus point I don't believe are causing the problem).

Comment: How big do you want the middle view to be? Do you want it to be as wide as the screen, and square? Should the bottom view grow/shrink to keep the middle view square?

Comment: @robmayoff Yes I want the bottom view to shrink to make the middle view square.